# KendoGrid datepicker selection saving date in wrong format

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo DatePicker inside KendoGrid using editor template (DD/MM/YYYY format), after changing the date via datepicker i see that its saving the data into grid modal with yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS format instead of DD/MM/YYYY. I am getting String from server in required DD/MM/YYYY format and display wise is also good only exception is during change of date via DatePicker.

### How can  i convert the date into required DD/MM/YYYY format while selecting date via datepicker?

```
function dateEditor(container, options) {
  $('<input name="'+options.field+'"data-text-field="'+options.field+'"data-value-field="'+options.field+'" data-bind="value:'+options.field+'" data-format="'+options.format+'"/>')
           .appendTo(container)
           .kendoDatePicker({
              format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
              parseFormats: ["MM/dd/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy"],


    change: function() {

        // If i try to override with MM/DD/YYYY format using below code  and trigger 
        //change event it goes into a infinite loop, so cant use this.

        //this.value(moment(this.value()).format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
            //this.trigger('change');
    }
    });
}
```

---

Please note that that requirement is not to use parameterMap as i am sending the data to server via below call so it picks the data directly from Grid without translating.
JSON.stringify($('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data())

Let me know if Jsfiddle can help the experts here ?